# Unable to write a script in pycharm for the code as i am very new to pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, robotframework

It is a button with absolute xpath being -

```
html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]
/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/a
```

and css path being -

```
<a id="gwt-uid-173" href="#nproject_portfolio-c100000000225500-ffalse"/>
```

I need to write a python script using the keyword Click button

Could you suggest me how should i write the xpath or using href?

Comment: try selenium python script. But do some research before asking

Comment: i am not sure how should i drill down the above xpath,could you please help,am very new to it

Comment: what stack are you using?

Comment: no i want to know how to make the above absolute xpath short like for "Ex-html/body/div/div/div[2]/a"

Comment: xpath afaik cant be shorten because they represent each element uniquely . I may be wrong

Answer (score 1):

Use the ID of the link tag in order to target it

```
Strategy    Example Description
id  Click Element | id=my_element   Matches by @id attribute
```

So in your case:

```
Click Element  id=gwt-uid-173
```

Let us know how that goes and update on issues encountered please